# Resources on how to create a NSIS plugin

Tags: c++, plugins, nsis

Is there documentation on how to write a NSIS plugin? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a simple [Dynamic-Link Library (DLL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682589(v=vs.85).aspx) with [DLL exports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4zxe9k8.aspx). The only "documentation" is the [example plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/nightly/Examples/Plugin/) and its [header file(s)](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/nightly/Examples/Plugin/nsis/pluginapi.h).

#### References

- [NSIS Nightly Repository on SourceForge](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/nightly/Examples/Plugin/)
- [MSDN Dynamic-Link Libraries Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682589(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [MSDN Exporting from a DLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4zxe9k8.aspx)